# Collect variables from hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, hash

I've got everything connected and it looks awesome. However I'm missing something in my code because I'm not able to get values out of the returned `Hash`. This is primarily using Koala Facebook gem in rails.

So far I've got:

```
def self.pull

   facebook = user.facebook.get_connection("me", "home")
   facebook.each do |story| # Each story is itself a Hash
       unless exists?(fb_id: story.id)
           NewStory.create({fb_id: story.id, fb_from_username: story.from.username, user_id: User.current, storystatus = 'new'})
       end
   end
end
```

Running `pull` I keep getting error `undefined method 'id' for #<Hash:0x007fc8f2784278>` ... I know its a `Hash` but I've never tried accessing the contents of a `Hash`

And example of the returned hash looks like this:

```
{
 "id"=>"650490971730768_650591128387419",
 "from"=>{
          "id"=>"650490971730768",
          "name"=>"Kathy Singer"
          }
 ...
}
```

Trying to start by grabbing the `id` then I'll move onto `from -> id` and `from -> user` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike ActiveRecord object attributes, you cannot access Hash values with `.` operator.

You should access it using [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
unless exists?(fb_id: story['id'])
```